# How to pull a count of cells with a missing date in a YYYY-MM-DD format?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to pull a count of cells that are missing the day and only have the month and year in the cell. I'm in pgAdmin and using PostGreSQL on a Mac.

This is the format of the date if everything is entered:

```
2010-01-01
```

So far, I have the following query started, with the date format just filled in for context:

```
SELECT COUNT(nct_id)
FROM studies
WHERE start_date LIKE '2010-01-NULL'
```

Comment: Please provide examples of valid and invalid dates.

Comment: Valid: 2010-01-01 Invalid: 2010-01

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that `start_date` is a string, not a `date`.  You really should store dates as dates, not string.

But, you can do what you want using regular expressions:

```
where not (start_date ~ '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$')
```

Comment: Yeah the weird thing is is that in the data dictionary, it says the start_date is a date, but I get an error when I don't put the ' ' around it. I tried that query and received an error: HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 318

Comment: @cpburke94 . . . If the value is a `date` then there is always a day component.

Comment: Oh that's right. Ok, I'm going to ask a new, separate question. There is a separate column for start_month_year that captures all of the studies without a date. I need to combine those two fields

Comment: What do you mean by "combine those two fields" Please at least provide an example of the combination.